# local bitmapimage(windows phone)

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am trying to convey the path for `<Image x:Name="FlagImage" Stretch="None" />`, but when I run the application image is not displayed.

```
FlagImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/sky.jpg"));
```

If I change the path to the URL the image is displayed

```
FlagImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www.charlespetzold.com/Media/HelloWP7.jpg"));
```

This Code work too:

```
<Image Source="/images/sky.jpg"/>
```

Comment: you have to set the relative source of image like in answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have initialize your bitmapimage urisource by setting its path to relative..like this

```
  FlagImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/sky.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
```

hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

I understand. It is necessary to add UriKind.Relative

```
FlagImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/sky.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
```